# Name of image slide control on Windows 8.1 Store App?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

[image]

I see this control (below photo) on Windows 8.1 Store app. It appears when have multi images, tap left and right button (red borders in photo) to navigate between images.

So my question is: Name of this control and link to tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `FlipView`, here is the docs from MS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/flipview